# javascript Unexpected illegal token

Tags: javascript

Hi I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error, when I run this code

```
str += "{'value': "+ response_imdb[count] +",
      'color':#"+ colorValue +",
      'label': "+ response_labels[count] +"
     }";
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you copy/pasted that code from somewhere, the problem is likely to be a stray invisible character somewhere in the text. Try typing the text in by hand. *edit* or the newline; gee I'm blind sometimes :)

Comment: does it say the line and token?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another easy way.

```js
str += JSON.stringify({
  value: response_imdb[count],
  color: '#' + colorValue,
  label: response_labels[count]
});
```

Comment: It's a nice way to do it, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: The answer was already posted by the time I posted the answer. I thought this was a good aside.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you cannot have multi-line strings ([unless you add a backslash to the end of each line](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/multiline-string-variables-in-javascript/)).

Make them multiple strings and concatenate them using `+`, like so:

```
str += "{'value': "+ response_imdb[count] +"," +
  "'color':#"+ colorValue +"," +
  "'label': "+ response_labels[count] +
 "}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't allow line breaks in strings. You heave line breaks after `",` at the end of each line. You should change it to:

```
str += "{'value': "+ response_imdb[count] +",\n"+
      'color':#"+ colorValue +",\n"+
      'label': "+ response_labels[count] +",\n"+
     }";
```

But it's almost always wrong to try to create JSON strings by hand. Use a function for it, like `JSON.stringify` in Javascript, `json_encode` in PHP, etc.

There are some other problems there. If the string is going to be parsed as JSON, it the property names need to be in double quotes, not single quotes. And `# + colorValue` needs to be in quotes to be a string.